# Problemas con mi propio plugin - CakePhp 3

Tags: plugin, cakephp

Estoy usando *Cakephp 3* y creé un plugin llamado *Intranet* usando *bake*:

```
bin/cake bake plugin Intranet
```

Esto me creó la estructura en:

> proyecto/plugins/Intranet

Luego creé un controlador llamado *Products*:

```
bin/cake bake controller --plugin Intranet Products
```

En el fichero `config/bootstrap.php` del proyecto añadí lo siguiente:

```
Plugin::load('Intranet', ['bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);
```

En `config/routes.php`:

```
Plugin::routes();
```

En el fichero `proyecto/plugins/Intranet/config/routes.php` tengo lo siguiente:

```
Router::plugin(
    'Intranet',
    ['path' => '/intranet'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    }
);
```

En `proyecto/plugins/Intranet/composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Intranet\\": "src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Intranet\\Test\\": "tests",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests"
    }
}
```

Cuando accedo a `http://site/intranet/products/index` obtengo el error:

> A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'users', 'action' =>
>   'login', 'prefix' => 'admin', '_mobile' => false, 'preview' => false,
>   'plugin' => 'Intranet', '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.

¿Cómo identifico el error? He probado algunas cosas, como poner:

```
Plugin::load('Intranet', ['autoload' => true, 'bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);
```

... y así en todas su variantes. Además intenté poner la ruta desde el fichero `routes.php` del proyecto, ejecuté los comandos:

```
composer update y composer dumpautoload
```

Sin resultados. El único error diferente era:

> Controller class Products could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Cuando crees el controlador usa las convenciones de cake

```
bin/cake bake ProductsController --plugin Intranet Products
```

Dentro del controlador creaste la funcion index?

```
public function index(){

echo "esta es mi pagina intranet";
}
```